# Oracle Webcenter Sites CSDT Plugin Export/Import

Tags: oracle, webcenter-sites

I want to export/import only site structure not the content using Oracle WCS CSDT Plugin command line tool.

Basically, I want empty site to be created on production env without content, and content editors will publish content from staging once basic site is available.

Does anyone has an idea, how I'll do it?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can mirror the site which doesn't publish any content.

on admin tab, select the site you want and double click on it. 
There you will see publish destinations. click on mirror site configuration for required environment and you can do it by selecting required things to mirror.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think this is the recommended way to do so, I actually think the CSDT tool isn't recommended by Oracle (will look up a source and amend my answer ASAP, just wanted to catch you before the irreversible happens).

Instead publish to the production environment from the current one, if it's not reachable you can publish to an installation on a portable machine (laptop or something) or maybe even a JSK (Jump Start Kit) on and the from the JSK to production.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although its been one year, just to answer this question, I am pointing out what I did in my past projects:

**I want to export/import only site structure not the content using Oracle WCS CSDT Plugin command line tool.**

Yes, this is quite feasible to do so via command line or even by using ANT or maven script

**Basically, I want empty site to be created on production env without content, and content editors will publish content from staging once basic site is available.**
Once site is imported using CSDT, editors can publish. But note: asset types, attributes, etc. which were created using your local instance or JSK will have different asset id as compared to Staging instance.

Hence, rather than using CSDT, preferred way is to just initialize site and then mirror assettypes, attributes, attribute editors, etc. from Staging to Production and then publish attributes, etc. from Staging to Production. When production is ready with all basic configurations, editors can just publish content as they see fit.